Show that the following the scheme is indistinguishably secure
Let $F$ be a PRP and $G$ be a PRG with expansion
factor $l(n) = n + 1$. To encrypt $m\in\{0,1\}^{n+1}$, output the cipher-text $Enc(k,m)=F_k(m\oplus G(k+1))$. Is this encryption scheme semantically secure?
Solution: I was trying to prove it secure using hybrid arguments. I constructed three hybrids as follows:
Hybrid $H_0:Enc(k,m)=F_k(m\oplus G(k+1))$
Hybrid $H_1:Enc(k,m)=F_k(m\oplus r)$, where $r\in_R\{0,1\}^{n+1}$
Hybrid $H_2:Enc(k,m) = TRP(m\oplus r)$, where $r\in_R\{0,1\}^{n+1}$
It is sufficient show that $H_0$ is computationally indistinguishable to $H_1$ and $H_1$ is computationally indistinguishable to $H_2$.
I have shown that $H_1$ is computationally indistinguishable to $H_2$. But I am not able to show that $H_0$ is computationally indistinguishable to $H_1$.

What is TRP, define it please

The scheme uses the same key for $G$ and $F$, which is why you are stuck trying to argue that $H_0 \approx H_1$. This question seems like it might be homework, so here's a hint: Design $G$ that is a secure PRG, but that causes $\textsf{Enc}(k,0^{n+1}) = 0^{n+1}$. Use the fact that $F$ is a permutation.

TRP means Truly Random Permutation

@Mikero It is not part of any homework or assignment. The original problem was to check whether it is CPA secure or not and obviously it is not CPA secure. Then I was thinking about semantic security and I think this is semantic secure so tried to prove it and got stuck.

I was trying another way also: $F_k(m_0\oplus G(k+1))\equiv F_k(m_0\oplus r)\equiv F_k(m_1\oplus r)\equiv F_k(m_1\oplus G(k+1))$
